# Need a matrix to seventh power which is the identity but the original is not or the negative identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question on the homework wants a $2\times2$ matrix $R$, but $R$ not equal to positive or negative identity, that when you raise to seventh power you get the identity.  $R^7=\operatorname{Id}$.  I thought it would have to be some ones and negative ones,  it no luck, then tried some ones and some $.5$.  Just using an online matrix calculator to do brute force.  We just started talking about eigenvalues with visual example, so assuming wouldn't need that since we have not talked about how to find them yet.  Any hints or ideas to get me back on track?

Comment: Would imaginary numbers maybe be it?  We use complex numbers sometimes

Comment: You can solve this by using a rotational matrix for $R$.

Comment: ($-I_2)^7=-I_2$, so it's a bit silly to eliminate the identity explicitly.

Answer (score 6):

Take$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}7\right)&-\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}7\right)\\\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}7\right)&\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}7\right)\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Since it's only required not to be $\pm \mathbb{1}$, $e^{2\pi i/7}\mathbb{1}$ would also work. Since the notation is $R$, I think your answer is what was wanted.

Comment: Since the above matrix is the unit circle divided into sevenths, when you do it you end up back at original?  0 degrees which is 1, 0, 1, o the identity?  Didn't think about that.......

Comment: I'm just using the fact that$$\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\alpha)&-\sin(\alpha)\\\sin(\alpha)&\cos(\alpha)\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(n\alpha)&-\sin(n\alpha)\\\sin(n\alpha)&\cos(n\alpha)\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Also a pretty cool relationship when you have two different rotational matrices corresponding to different angles $R(\theta)$ and $R(\phi)$ : $R(\theta)R(\phi)=R(\theta + \phi)$