# A matrix $R$ where $R\neq I$ but $R^7=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble trying to find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $R$ in which $R$ is not equal to $I$, but $R^7=I$.

I thought to start with the matrix
$$ \begin{bmatrix} \cos x & -\sin x \\ \sin x & \cos x\end{bmatrix}$$
was a good place to start
but what I got when trying a sample run on my calculator was that it comes out to the same matrix as $R$. Any suggestions of how I should approach this? Or should I use a very specific value for $x$? The value I used on my calc was $\pi/3$ just to avoid it being equal to the identity matrix.

Comment: This very question was asked just a few days ago ...

Comment: @Bram28 can you link to it?

Comment: I was just searching for it .. and found it! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2491555/need-a-matrix-to-seventh-power-which-is-the-identity-but-the-original-is-not-or

Answer (score 1):

Define the following rotation matrix

$$R(\alpha) =\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{bmatrix}$$

by using addition formulas for sine and cosine you can easily show

$$R(\alpha_1)R(\alpha_2)=R(\alpha_1+\alpha_2).$$

We will look at the general case

$$R^k=I$$

note that by extending $R$ to higher dimensions we can quickly get $n$-dimensional matrices with such a property.

**The Method:** Set $\alpha =2\pi/k$ then

$$\underbrace{R\cdot R \cdot \ldots \cdot R}_{k \text{ times}}=R^k(\alpha)=R(k\alpha)=R(2\pi)=I$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix
$$
R =\begin{pmatrix} e^{2\pi i/7} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Of course, $R\neq I$, but $R^7=I$.